# Codeigniter-HMVC get_instance() in library does not return expected result

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I have the Controller:

> application/controllers/bob.php

Then in a library I use in the controller Bob.php, I have this code:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
echo get_class($CI);
```

So I open the url "domain.com/bob", and I get the correct echo when HMVC is not installed, which is

- Bob

As soon as I install HMVC, the result is:

- CI

So basically, this means I cannot use $CI->someVariableINeed that was declared in Bob because it doesn't exists in CI. Note that $CI->load->helper(), $CI->load->view(), .. are all working however. I tried:

```
class Bob extends CI_Controller
```

and

```
class Bob extends MX_Controller
```

but it still doesn't work. I've been searching for 24 hours and did not find anything, hopefully someone on SO knows about this. I understand that this is not a very clean way to access members of a class, but this problem is a simplification of an existing project with hundreds of thousands of lines of code, so I cannot change this, the library HAS to access these member variables least I change the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes!! I'm the man, I fixed it! Thought about maybe creating my "own" get_instance() system, here's what I did:

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller
{
    public static $instance;
    function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance || self::$instance =& $this;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in the library, or in the helper or wherever funky place you need to use it:

```
$CI =& MY_Controller::$instance;
```

**NOTE that if you autoload a library, MY_Controller::$instance won't work if it's in the library's __construct(), as MY_Controller is not defined yet**