# CodeIgniter - HMVC, Helpers and Undefined property

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I use WireDesignz HMVC and have a KERNEL_Controller (which is actually the MY_Controller with another prefix) using CodeIgniter 3.0.6

```
class KERNEL_Controller extends MX_Controller {
    public $myvar;

    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            //Load core Model
            $this->load->model('Core_model');

            $this->myvar = 'test';
    }
}
```

Now I have an Helper which does the following

```
function Editor($id) {
    $ci =& get_instance();

    echo $ci->myvar;
}
```

When I call the Editor in a view, I get

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI::$myvar
Filename: helpers/editor_helper.php
```

*Same when calling a method in the Editor Helper*

In the KERNEL_Controller I have

```
public function DoTest() {
    echo '1';
}
```

And in the Editor_helper

```
function Editor($id) {
    $ci =& get_instance();    
    echo $ci->DoTest();
}
```

I get, when calling the Editor in a view

```
Type: Error
Message: Call to undefined method CI::DoTest()
```

But when I call to a Model in the Editor Helper

```
function Editor($id) {
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $result_content = $ci->Core_model->GetLanguages(1);
    print_r($result_content);
}
```

I do get (in this case) an array with languages back.

Comment: `get_instance` returns `CodeIgniter` class, not your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes!! I'm the man, I fixed it! Thought about maybe creating my "own" get_instance() system, here's what I did:

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller
{
    public static $instance;
    function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance || self::$instance =& $this;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in the library, or in the helper or wherever funky place you need to use it:

```
$CI =& MY_Controller::$instance;
```

NOTE that if you autoload a library, MY_Controller::$instance won't work if it's in the library's __construct(), as MY_Controller is not defined yet

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433210](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433210/codeigniter-hmvc-get-instance-in-library-does-not-return-expected-result)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc you have to use something like

```
<?php
/** module and controller names are different, you must include the method name also, including 'index' **/
modules::run('module/controller/method', $params, $...);

/** module and controller names are the same but the method is not 'index' **/
modules::run('module/method', $params, $...);

/** module and controller names are the same and the method is 'index' **/
modules::run('module', $params, $...);

/** Parameters are optional, You may pass any number of parameters. **/
```

I don't know how your module is called, but you can try

```
modules::run('module/KERNEL/DoTest');
```

in order to invoke method `DoTest` of `KERNEL` controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: 
I tried something like above, but it didn't do the trick. The KERNEL_controller is actually the MY_controller with another prefix.

In another project I can use the method DoTest in the KERNEL controller, but there the KERNEL controller is not extended by the MX_Controller but with the CI_Controller

Comment: The error is Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI::$myvar 

or with the method I get

Undefined property: CI::$DoTest

I also edited my Topic Start, as you can see using Core_model in the Editor helper works, so I don't get why the other aint working

Comment: No, those errors are from your examples from the post. I'm asking about `modules::run` call. Or was it the same?

Comment: Oke, there is no error message at all when using `modules::run` . Probably the MX addon checks if the module exists.
I think this is because KERNEL_controller is not a module. Its in the application/core folder

Comment: If it's not a module, why do you use WireDesignz HMVC? Why not use simple controllers? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I do use HMVC, but not for that particulair piece of code. But I think I will give the Editor an extra parameter.